# Calculations in Wallpaper Cropper

Tags: android, wallpaper

I need to know why this extraspace is added as left margin. Due to this wakllpaper is not setting properly in my app. If i try to set leftmost portion as wallpaper then centre portion is getting set as wallpaper due to this extraspace margin.
cropImageAndSetWallpaper(android.net.Uri uri, com.android.wallpapercropper.WallpaperCropActivity$OnBitmapCroppedHandler onBitmapCroppedHandler, boolean finishActivityWhenDone)

```
    boolean centerCrop = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.center_crop);
    // Get the crop
    boolean ltr = mCropView.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR;

    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point displaySize = new Point();
    d.getSize(displaySize);
    boolean isPortrait = displaySize.x < displaySize.y;

    Point defaultWallpaperSize = getDefaultWallpaperSize(getResources(),
            getWindowManager());
    // Get the crop
    RectF cropRect = mCropView.getCrop();

    Point inSize = mCropView.getSourceDimensions();

    int cropRotation = mCropView.getImageRotation();
    float cropScale = mCropView.getWidth() / (float) cropRect.width();

    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
    rotateMatrix.setRotate(cropRotation);
    float[] rotatedInSize = new float[] { inSize.x, inSize.y };
    rotateMatrix.mapPoints(rotatedInSize);
    rotatedInSize[0] = Math.abs(rotatedInSize[0]);
    rotatedInSize[1] = Math.abs(rotatedInSize[1]);

    // Due to rounding errors in the cropview renderer the edges can be slightly offset
    // therefore we ensure that the boundaries are sanely defined
    cropRect.left = Math.max(0, cropRect.left);
    cropRect.right = Math.min(rotatedInSize[0], cropRect.right);
    cropRect.top = Math.max(0, cropRect.top);
    cropRect.bottom = Math.min(rotatedInSize[1], cropRect.bottom);

    // ADJUST CROP WIDTH
    // Extend the crop all the way to the right, for parallax
    // (or all the way to the left, in RTL)
    float extraSpace;
    if (centerCrop) {
        extraSpace = 2f * Math.min(rotatedInSize[0] - cropRect.right, cropRect.left);
    } else {
        extraSpace = ltr ? rotatedInSize[0] - cropRect.right : cropRect.left;
    }
    // Cap the amount of extra width
    float maxExtraSpace = defaultWallpaperSize.x / cropScale - cropRect.width();
    extraSpace = Math.min(extraSpace, maxExtraSpace);

    if (centerCrop) {
        cropRect.left -= extraSpace / 2f;
        cropRect.right += extraSpace / 2f;
    } else {
        if (ltr) {
            cropRect.right += extraSpace;
        } else {
            cropRect.left -= extraSpace;
        }
    }

    // ADJUST CROP HEIGHT
    if (isPortrait) {
        cropRect.bottom = cropRect.top + defaultWallpaperSize.y / cropScale;
    } else { // LANDSCAPE
        float extraPortraitHeight =
                defaultWallpaperSize.y / cropScale - cropRect.height();
        float expandHeight =
                Math.min(Math.min(rotatedInSize[1] - cropRect.bottom, cropRect.top),
                        extraPortraitHeight / 2);
        cropRect.top -= expandHeight;
        cropRect.bottom += expandHeight;
    }
    final int outWidth = (int) Math.round(cropRect.width() * cropScale);
    final int outHeight = (int) Math.round(cropRect.height() * cropScale);

    Runnable onEndCrop = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (finishActivityWhenDone) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    BitmapCropTask cropTask = new BitmapCropTask(this, uri,
            cropRect, cropRotation, outWidth, outHeight, true, false, onEndCrop);
    if (onBitmapCroppedHandler != null) {
        cropTask.setOnBitmapCropped(onBitmapCroppedHandler);
    }
    cropTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra space is added to the wallpaper to allow for a parallax effect. In case your phone uses a right-to-left layout, this space is added to the left of the crop you chose. Google's launcher starts out on the rightmost page in RTL layouts.

If you choose a crop on the left side of the picture, then the expansion will take place on the right side of the crop, an you will see mainly this extension on the main page of the launcher.